# Updating zlib stream to work with Node 5.0.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

My current function which used to work before Node 5.0 was :

```
var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();
var xml = new xmlStream(stream.pipe(gunzip));
    xml.preserve('product>attributeClass');
        xml.on('updateElement:merchandiser>product',self._createProduct.bind(self));
    xml.on('end', function() {
        console.log('xmlend');
        self._processList();
    });
    xml.on('error',function(){
        console.log('xmlerr');
    });
```

it reads huge gz files from a FTP repo, and I'd like to keep not writing anything to disk and handle everything with streams.

Now, I understand that the patched zlib requires me to make changes to handle the end event or risk the 'unexpected end of input' which now happens randomly. ([source on Node repo](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4030)).

But I'm not exactly sure what to do. I've tried forcing gunzip to not send its 'end' event, but it just stalls my xmlStream. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!

Edit : In the meantime, using node 4.2.6 fixed it. Still curious as of how to update though.